# Trouble converting regex

Tags: regex, boost

This regex:

```
"REGION\\((.*?)\\)(.*?)END_REGION\\((.*?)\\)"
```

currently finds this info:

```
REGION(Test) my user typed this

END_REGION(Test)
```

I need it to instead find this info:

```
#region REGION my user typed this

#endregion END_REGION
```

I have tried:

```
"#region\\ (.*?)\\\n(.*?)#endregion\\ (.*?)\\\n"
```

It tells me that the pattern assignment has failed. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? I am new to Regex.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue lies in the multiline `\n`. My recommendation is to use the modifier `s` to avoid multiline complexities like:

```
/#region\ \(.*?\)(.*?)\s#endregion\s\(.*?\)/s
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oN9sB4/2)

- **`s`**  modifier "single line" makes the `.` to match all characters, including line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#region(.*)?\n(.*)?#endregion(.*)?
```

This works for me when testing here: http://regexpal.com/

When using your original text and regex, the only thing that threw it off is that I did not have a new line at the end because your sample text didn't have one.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing this regex doesn't fail using boost, even if you use the expanded modifier.

Your string to the compiler:

```
"#region\\ (.*?)\\\n(.*?)#endregion\\ (.*?)\\\n"
```

After parsed by compiler:

```
#region\ (.*?)\\n(.*?)#endregion\ (.*?)\\n
```

It looks like you have one too many escapes on the newline.

if you present the regex as expanded to boost, an un-escaped pound sign `#` is interpreted as a comment.
In that case, you need to escape the pound sign.

```
\#region\ (.*?)\\n(.*?)\#endregion\ (.*?)\\n
```

If you don't use the expanded modifier, then you don't need to escape the space characters.
Taking that tack, you can remove the escape on the space's, and fixing up the newline escapes, it looks like this raw (what gets passed to regex engine):

```
#region (.*?)\n(.*?)#endregion (.*?)\n
```

And like this as a source code string:

```
"#region (.*?)\\n(.*?)#endregion (.*?)\\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression has an extra backslash when escaping the newline sequence `\\\n`, use `\\s*` instead. Also for the last capturing group you can use a greedy quantifier instead and remove the newline sequence.

```
#region\\ (.*?)\\s*(.*?)#endregion\\ (.*)
```

[<kbd>Compiled Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4c9d1eb1c56e78f)